# App running problems with grails and groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, cmd, installation

When I try to run my new app in grails I get this problem [Click here](http://gyazo.com/4078265ae02c077c87e1b5279315cc4a) what is it and how do I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is saying exactly, but if you don't need the database migration plugin then just remote it from your plugins block in BuildConfig.groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11063) related to Grails incompatibility with JDK 8 which I think will be fixed with version 2.4 or higher. Downgrade to JDK 7 to use latest version of Grails.

Database migration plugin has nothing to do with it. There is a [JIRA (not an)issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION-171) raised few days back before realizing it is actually an issue related to JDK 8.